# How to solve Catalog Rule Product Status: REINDEX REQUIRED

Tags: admin-panel, catalog-rules, magento2.1.5

How to solve Catalog Rule Product Status: REINDEX REQUIRED
Hi,
I have a problem in admin, One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.
I am using cpanel in host. How can i solve this problem?

Thank you for your help!
Angelo
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may go to phpmyadmin and in your database check table cron_schedule and see if there is an entry for your reindexing cron job.

If you want to do it manually then connect your ssh to your server. If ssh is enabled then use this command

```
ssh username@host
```

enter your password and then run this command in terminal

```
php bin/Magento indexer:reindex
```

this will reindex your indices

Comment: Hi Simplysaif,
I check table cron_schedule.

SELECT * 
FROM  `mgyy_cron_schedule` 
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: There are many services which are carried out with cron like email so to check if your cron is working you may try to send an email. Try to reset password for a valid email account and see if you get an email for the same

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Following steps did the job for me.

**Step ONE**
Fom the cli, run:

```
php bin/magento indexer:status
```

Check if your indexer is listed with "Reindex required".
It should, because if it's not listed, it means that you don't have a reindexing problem.

**Step TWO:**
 From the cli, run TWICE (!):

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

See [this link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html) why you have to run the cron twice.
In short: first time cron runs to check for tasks; second time cron executes the found tasks.

**Step THREE**
Check your indexers in cli or M2 admin.

All indexers should be ready.